# Use $geowithin on multiple boxes - mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pymongo, geojson, aggregation-framework

I need to search all the Points lying in boxes. So I am using following query in mongoDB

```js
db.places.find({ 
    "loc" : { 
        "$geoWithin" : { 
            "$box": [ 
                [ 0 , 0 ] ,
                [ 100 , 100 ]
             ] 
         }
     } 
})
```

Now I have multiple boxes to be searched within and I want to get all the Points that lie in any of the boxes. I want something like

```js
db.places.find({ 
    "loc": { 
        "$geoWithin": { 
            "$box":[ [ 0 , 0 ], [ 25 , 25 ] ],
                [ [ 40 , 40 ] , [ 75 , 75 ] ],
                [ [ 90 , 90 ] , [ 100 , 100 ] ] 
         }
     }
})
```

I can't use `$or` as its does *Short-Circuit evaluation*. I can't also use *aggregation* as only `$geonear` is supported in *aggregation*. I don't want to hit one seperate query for each box. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

There are some "shortcut" type operators available for "geo" type queries that are pre-defined such as **`$box`**. But for anything more advanced you are actually going to want to formally declare the GeoJSON structure and use the **`$geometry`** operator instead:

So if you consider the following documents:

```js
{ "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 3, 6 ] } }
{ "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 9, 12 ] } }
{ "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 45, 45 ] } }
{ "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 30, 30 ] } }
{ "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 76, 76 ] } }
```

With then the following query:

```js
db.geo.find({
    "loc": {
        "$geoWithin": {
            "$geometry":{
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [[ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 25 ], [ 25, 25 ], [ 25, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ]],
                    [[ [ 40, 40 ], [ 40, 75 ], [ 75, 75 ], [ 75, 40 ], [ 40, 40 ] ]],
                    [[ [ 80, 80 ], [ 80, 90 ], [ 90, 90 ], [ 90, 80 ], [ 80, 80 ] ]]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

You would get the returned result:

```js
{ "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 3, 6 ] } }
{ "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 9, 12 ] } }
{ "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 45, 45 ] } }
```

So the full support for GeoJSON geometry is what you need for this type of query.

This definitely works with MongoDB 2.6 and should also be the case with 2.4.10. The extended GeoJSON types are available for indexes as of these releases, but (untried) possibly do work as a query form in earlier 2.4 versions.

Comment: Does this also work for more complex Polygons. I've followed your directions however the matches I'm getting seem to come from where the polygons overlap